# Linq Comparing Two Lists and Generating a New One

Tags: c#, linq

I am Working on a MVC4 project and I am in need to create a new list of objects by comparing two lists. `db` below refers to the `DbContext` object.

In the project that I work, I am in need of comparing two lists. The first has all the subjects offered in a semester. The other has the subjects selected by the student.

```
List<Subject> subjects = db.Subjects;
//...
List<Subject> semesterSubjects = student.Subjects;
```

Out of this two lists I need to create a list of items that state if or not each an every item is selected. It looks like this.

```
class SubjectSelection
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public String Title { get; set; }
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

What I need now is to compare `subjects` & `semesterSubjects` and get a `IEnumerable<SubjectSelection>`

Could I use Linq to get such a result and how?

Comment: Ziyan, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to do this job on the server side. Select ids from your semester subjects:

```
var selectedIDs = semesterSubjects.Select(s => s.ID).ToList();
```

And pass them to query:

```
var query = db.Subjects.Select(s => new SubjectSelection()
                     {
                        ID = s.ID,
                        Title = s.Title,
                        IsSelected = selectedIDs.Contains(s.ID)
                     });
```

If you are using same db context instance to retrieve both semester subjects list and subjects list, then you can simply use:

```
var query = subjects.Select(s => new SubjectSelection()
                     {
                        ID = s.ID,
                        Title = s.Title,
                        IsSelected = semesterSubjects.Contains(s)
                     });
```

Entity Framework implements identity map pattern, which means it returns same in-memory instance of subject object, which returned by different queries.

Comment: I updated solution, because searching by objects equality available only if your selected subjects where loaded from same context, as all subjects list.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like working!!! You answered so quick, I doubt if you are lazy after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var allSubjectsWithSelection = subjects.Select(o=>new SubjectSelection(){ID = o.ID,Title = o.Title, IsSelected = semesterSubjects.Any(s=>s.ID == o.ID)}).ToList();
```